# Will debris in the supply lines cause issues?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

While trying to retrieve a torn rubber washer from a tap some of it went down into the tap pipes.

Will this cause problems to the boiler or anything else?

Comment: Be sure to remove the aerator from time-to-time to flush junk in the pipes that is pushed to the sink via pressure. https://www.thisoldhouse.com/kitchens/21097151/the-anatomy-of-a-kitchen-faucet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles like that can cause clogs so it's good to try and remove it. With the tap removed, turn the system back on so water flows up and out of the tap pipe. The water pressure should be enough to force the washer parts out of the pipe. Then reinstall the tap.

Comment: When you say "back flush the boiler or just the tap pipe if the configuration allows it", wouldn't that simply be "open the tap & let water run"? How would a pipe from the hot water heater/boiler be configured in any other way?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm assuming the OP has removed the tap to replace the washer so the system's been shut down. So open the main valve and flush out the questioned pipe with it's tap still removed. Will edit answer due to it being confusing